# How to create a Data View webpart?

Tags: web-part, wss-3.0

How to create Data View Webpart?

or is a free webpart available on the net?

I use WSS 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marc Anderson has an excellent blog with lots of DVWP resources: http://sympmarc.com/tag/dvwp/

There's also some really good articles by Jim Bob Howard (and others) on EndUserSharePoint.com: http://www.endusersharepoint.com/tag/data-view-web-part/

Answer (score 2):

Use SharePoint Designer.

Here's a good start:

http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/08/24/your-first-data-view-web-part/

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Mike and James about the links above. They noted some of my favorite DVWP bloggers.

I also like to read Laura Rogers on the topic.  She has screencasts available at: http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Pages/Data%20View%20Web%20Part%20Screencasts.aspx

I did a series on our company blog where I use "Data Forms" and "Data View Web Parts" interchangeably.  http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Pages/Data%20View%20Web%20Part%20Screencasts.aspx

To keep you from having to dig too deep into all our links, DVWP's are authored using SharePoint Designer 2007 (in your case) and can be used with WSS 3.0.  So if you download SPD2007 (for free) you are good to go.